# Connected Tf tree for multimaster turtlebots

Tags: ros, multimaster, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, has anyone find ways to connect multiple tf trees from different master into a single tf tree?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215676/connected-tf-tree-for-multimaster-turtlebots/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2015-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, if you are forwarding the tf data between the masters you just need to publish a transform between the root of one tree and any frame on the other tree (often it will also be the root as well such as the map. Maybe an identity transform between map frames.)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1